File corrupts when uploading using pre-signed url with AWS Lambda
I am trying to load files uploaded using Angular application to S3 using presigned URL but file gets corrupted after upload. It works using postman.
Lambda FastAPI function to handle the upload-
async def temp_upload_file_to_s3(email_id: str = Form(...),file: List[UploadFile] = File(...),db: connection = Depends(get_db_connection)):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    for file1 in file:
        key = 'raw/' + file1.filename
        presigned_url = await generate_presigned_url(key, 'put_object')
        print(presigned_url)
        response = requests.put(presigned_url, data=await file1.read())
        print(response)
    return {"status": "success", "message": "Files uploaded to S3"}

